# Видеопоток с ip камеры. Трансляция на сайт

Tags: html, камера, web-camera

Есть ip адрес камеры. Поток идет через порт 8081. Открывается только через IE, установив плагин tfocx. Остальные браузеры выводят просто черный экран. Есть ли возможность установить трансляцию на сайт? Может - быть, библиотека какая - нибудь.  Что бы любой, зашедший на страницу, видел поток с камеры? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас IP-камера, то она с большой вероятностью отдаёт поток в RTSP. Поток RTSP ни один из известных мне плееров для сайта воспроизводить не умеет. Плюс видео-поток с камеры отдавать сразу посетителям сайта не самая хорошая идей, т. к. проблемы с воспроизведением могут начаться уже при пяти посетителях (которые смотрят камеру).

Если транслировать видео с камеры на сайте всё-таки хочется, то варианты для вас:

1. Собрать мини стримминг-сервер на ffmpeg и NGINX и воспроизводить поток на сайте через JWPlayer (https://www.sinyawskiy.ru/nginxrtmpmodule.html). В этом случае вам придётся держать свой сервер со всеми вытекающими.
2. Воспользоваться онлайн сервисами, которые умеют шарить видео-поток. Например, [lideo](http://lideo.ru/) или [Ivideon](https://ru.ivideon.com/help/vozmozhnosti-ivideon/dobavlyajte-kameru-v-ivideon-tv/). В этом случае делать практически ничего не нужно (только разместить спец. код на своём сайте).

Comment: ВТОРОЙ СПОСОБ ПЛАТНЫЙ и тупит нереально

Comment: Думаю, что должны бысть варианты с бесплатной трансляцией во втором способе. С водяным знаком, возможно, но всё же.